# Is there a way to accept entities in SOAP request using axis2

Tags: xml-parsing, entity, apache-axis, woodstox

Currently I am not having any problem with entities
`&lt; &gt; &apos; &amp;.` But if i provide some other entities, following error comes in axis2

```
faultstring>com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared general entity "Euml"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,28]</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <Exception>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared general entity "Euml"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,28]
```

iS there a way to add entity resolver in axis2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Entities require a Document Type Declaration, but SOAP explicitly forbids DTDs. Axis2 strictly enforce this because not doing so would be a [security risk](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/core/security/CVE-2010-1632.pdf).